# How to read Android Clipboard (text) when opening an app?

Tags: android, clipboard

I am making an app and eventually I want to check the clipboard's content right when user opens my app with a regex in order to offer an action. I'm currently trying to be sure that I get the data properly by displaying it in a Toast.

I am using ClipboardManager on my MainActivity's OnCreate function as described in the official documentation and many other places, although I get a null pointer error when trying to access clipboard's data.

But, if I set a delay of 1-2 seconds before trying to get that data (I use handler.postDelayed for the delayed action), I can read the clipboard's content properly, which is odd...

Why does that happen and how to access clipboard's data without any delay, right when app is opened?

The code I use is:

```
ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);;
ClipData clipData = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(0);
String clipText = item.getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), clipText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And it crashes in 3rd line with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ClipData$Item android.content.ClipData.getItemAt(int)' on a null object reference
```

Thank you

Comment: You are going to need to wait until your UI is in the foreground to be able to read the clipboard. If your code shown above is on `onCreate()` of an activity, that is probably too soon.

Comment: Thank you, I assumed by the time `onCreate()` is done, the app is already on the foreground. Do you have any ideas on how to "wait until UI is in the foreground" so that I can access the clipboard but only on app startup?

Comment: get clipboard in `onResume()`

Comment: @PouriaHemati `onResume()` would get called only when activity gets focus after losing it first, does not seem like a good match for what I need... https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onresume
I already resolved the issue though by using `onWindowFocusChanged()`, along with a flag so that it runs only once, on app startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was running the code that accesses the clipboard in `onWindowFocusChanged()` as since Android 10, app needs to have input focus in order to access the clipboard, as @laalto pointed out.

Although that created another problem since I need the code to run only on app launch and not every time activity has focus (change of activities, pausing the app and returning, etc).

My approach to that was to create a static boolean variable within the class, then make that variable true within `onCreate()` and set an if condition on `onWindowFocusChanged()` to run the code that interacts with clipboard only if that variable is true.
Once I'm done with accessing the clipboard on `onWindowFocusChanged()`, I make that variable false.

By doing that, the code is run only on app's launch and not every time MainActivity has focus.

Answer (score 4):

As of Android 10 and later, your app needs to have input focus to read clipboard successfully. Otherwise `getPrimaryClip()` returns null.

`onCreate()` is too early for your activity to have input focus. You can override `onWindowFocusChanged()` to attempt to read the clipboard as soon as there is focus.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, thank you. I was not sure what "input focus" was referring to when I read about it in documentation.
As for `onWindowFocusChanged()` it does help using that, although it's doing the actions defined in it even when switching from another activity back to the main one, not only on app startup, which is not ideal.